Do we follow the same policy as the other SE sites about "noise" on questions / answers?
I often stumble across questions / answers containing "background noise" such as greetings, salutations, thanksgivings and so on.
Should this "background noise" be edited out of the post?
Greetings / salutations / thanksgivings are indeed polite and welcome themselves, but for the sake of a post's readability I believe those should be removed, since in the end they don't really add anything to the post itself.

Related question: http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/179/users-opinion-about-moderator-policy-on-added-noise-to-questions-answers.

@Charo Sorry, I didn't manage to find that question. Maybe you can close this one as a duplicate of that one? This one seems to be mostly a subset of that one (the point after all is: "remove whatever unnecessarily lengthens the post", which should cover these cases as well).

I agree it's a duplicate in the sense you have said and that it can be closed.
